# javafx 2- tableview dynamic column

Tags: javafx-2, tableview

Can someone suggest issue in below code. I am not able to populate data in table. 
This code basically should add one column (col1) and add one row with data d1 in it. This code is able to add column but not data.

Controller -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class FXMLTableViewController {
    @FXML private TableView tableView;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
        columns.add("col1");
        TableColumn [] tableColumns = new TableColumn[columns.size()];     
        int columnIndex = 0;
        for(String columName : columns) {
            tableColumns[columnIndex++] = new TableColumn(columName);
        }
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(tableColumns);
        ObservableList<ObservableList> csvData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        row.addAll("d1");
        csvData.add(row);
        tableView.getItems().add(csvData);

    }

    }
```

fxml

```
<?import javafx.collections.*?> 
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import fxmltableview.*?>


<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10.0" vgap="10.0" fx:controller="FXMLTableViewController"
             xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
     <TableView fx:id="tableView" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
          <columns>
          </columns>    
     </TableView>
</GridPane>
```

Main Class -

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXMLTableView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("FXML TableView Example");
        Pane myPane = (Pane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_tableview.fxml"));
        Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see "Example 12-12 Adding Map Data to the Table" of [Oracle's TableView Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm).

Comment: Hi Uluk, i am looking for tableview code, in which number of column is not fixed (i.e. it can change at run time, lets say, based on db query). I have got one java object which as fixed row (i.e. 5 rows but variable number of column)

Answer (score 7):

Try the below code it will showing the same as you need

```
List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
    columns.add("col1");
    columns.add("col2");
    TableColumn [] tableColumns = new TableColumn[columns.size()];     
    int columnIndex = 0;
    for(int i=0 ; i<columns.size(); i++) {
        final int j = i;
        TableColumn col = new TableColumn(columns.get(i));
        col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                   
           public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                             
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                       
            }                   
        });
        tableview.getColumns().addAll(col);
    }       
    ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<String> row1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    row.addAll("d1");
    row.addAll("d11");
    row1.addAll("d2");
    row1.addAll("d22");
    tableview.getItems().add(row);
    tableview.getItems().add(row1);
```

Comment: Got compilation error `The method get(int) is undefined for the type TreeItem<ObservableList>`.

Answer (score 1):

I m sure it will help you

```
public class DBClass 
{    
 public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
 {       
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1:3306   /dbname","mysqluser","mysqluserpwd"); 
 }
}
```

In Controller Class do the following :

```
@FXML
void initialize() 
{
 assert tableview != null : "fx:id=\"tableview\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'UserMaster.fxml'.";
 colUserName.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<Usermaster,String>("userName"));        
colPassword.setCellValueFactory(                
    new PropertyValueFactory<Usermaster,String>("userPassword"));
colUserType.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<Usermaster,String>("userType"));        
colPhoto.setCellValueFactory(
    new PropertyValueFactory<Object,ImageView>("userPhoto"));
objDbClass = new DBClass();
try
{
    con = objDbClass.getConnection();
    buildData();
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException ce)
{
    logger.info(ce.toString());
}
catch(SQLException ce)
{
    logger.info(ce.toString());
}
}

private ObservableList<Usermaster> data;

public void buildData()
{        
data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
try
{      
    String SQL = "Select * from usermaster Order By UserName";            
    ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);  
    while(rs.next())
    {
        Usermaster cm = new Usermaster();
        cm.userId.set(rs.getInt("UserId"));                       
        Image img = new Image("tailoring/UserPhoto/User"+cm.getUserId().toString()+".jpg");                

        ImageView mv = new ImageView();
        mv.setImage(img);
        mv.setFitWidth(70);
        mv.setFitHeight(80);
        cm.userPhoto.set(mv);
        cm.userName.set(rs.getString("UserName"));
        cm.userPassword.set(rs.getString("UserPassword"));
        cm.userType.set(rs.getString("UserType"));
        data.add(cm);                  
    }
    tableview.setItems(data);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("Error on Building Data");            
}
}
```

and Create a POJO a seperate java file for every entity(table) to want to manipulate using TableView

```
public class Usermaster 
{    

 public SimpleIntegerProperty userId = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
  public ObjectProperty userPhoto = new SimpleObjectProperty();
  public SimpleStringProperty userName = new SimpleStringProperty(); 
 public SimpleStringProperty userPassword = new SimpleStringProperty();
  public SimpleStringProperty userType = new SimpleStringProperty();
  public SimpleStringProperty encPass = new SimpleStringProperty();
 public SimpleStringProperty updt = new SimpleStringProperty();
  public SimpleStringProperty uptm = new SimpleStringProperty();

 public Integer getUserId() {
  return userId.get();
  }

  public Object getUserPhoto() {
  return userPhoto.get();
  }

 public String getUserName() {
  return userName.get();
  }

  public String getUserPassword() {
  return userPassword.get();
  }

  public String getUserType() {
    return userType.get();
  }

   public String getEncPass() {
   return encPass.get();
   }

   public String getUpdt() {
     return updt.get();
 }

public String getUptm() 
{
  return uptm.get();
}
}
```

I have tested this program it working perfectly.

Comment: where do you have colUserName defined ?

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to add columns during run time

you did well using ArrayList for columns.
you should do the same for tableColumns, otherwise it's still fixed number of columns.

```
List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
List<TableColumn> tableColumns = new ArrayList<TableColumn>;
```

the reason "d1" doesn't appear is because 
while you have properly linked the data to the table

```
tableView.getItems().add(csvData);
```

you forgot to link the datafields to the columns, you should add

```
tableColumns[i].setCellValueFactory("sorry, I have no idea what to write here in your case");
```