# Simple way to add more then 100 named Columns to a JavaFX Tableview

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

in my Project I need to add more then 100 Columns to an Tablevie in the JavaFX GUI, latere I have to fill this columns with data. Each Column have to have a specific name, than I have unsorted Data wich have to be includet, sometimes also a column can be empty this depends on the data. To include the data, I have to know the name of the Column.

In short, I have to sort many data into more then 100 Columns in a Tablevie.

The Tableview is created with Scenebuilder and is empty at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves out a lot of information specific to your case but I will try my best to give you a generic way of doing things. Depending on your needs you might need to modify it.

Obviously working with this amount of data is cumbersome, and displaying over 100 columns in a tableview doesn't seem like a good solution since you will get horizontal overflow no matter what you do since no screen will be able to show all data without scrolling. But I'm under the assumption that this is something you are aware of and is necessary for your implementation.

If the case is that you know before hand what the columns will be, I would go about it this way:

First of create a DataContainer class as a way of storing the data you want represented in your tableview.

```
public class DataContainer
{
    private String dataValue1;
    private String dataValue2;
    // Repeat for all the data you need represented.

    public DataContainer(String dataValue1,
                         String dataValue2,
                         //And so on.)
    {
         this.dataValue1 = dataValue1;
         this.dataValue2 = dataValue2;
         //And so on.
    }

    public String getDataValue1()
    {
        return this.dataValue1;
    }

    public String setDataValue1(String value)
    {
        this.dataValue1 = value;
    }

    public String getDataValue2()
    {
        return this.dataValue1;
    }

    public String setDataValue2(String value)
    {
        this.dataValue2 = value;
    }

    //Repeat for all data.
}
```

How you receive the data and sort it is obviously up to you but would look something like this:

```
ArrayList<DataContainer> data;

//Depends on how you receive your data.
foreach(InputData dataObject in recievedData)
{
     DataContainer newDataContainer = new DataContainer(dataObject.dataValue1,
                                                        dataObject.dataValue2,
                                                        //And so on.
                                                        );
     data.add(newDataContainer);
}

ObservableList<DataContainer> observableData = FXCollections.observabaleArrayList<DataContainer>(data);
```

Finally create all columns in your tableview and assign the data. Maybe you can do this with an algorithm, maybe you have to specify each column individually. Depends on your implementation.

```
TableColumn value1 = new TableColumn("Value 1");
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DataContainer, String>("dataValue1")); //The string corresponds to the member name of that dataValue in the DataContainer class.
TableColumn value2 = new TableColumn("Value 2");
firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<DataContainer, String>("dataValue2")); //The string corresponds to the member name of that dataValue in the DataContainer class.

table.setItems(observableData);
table.getColumns().addAll(value1, value2); //For all columns.
```

I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question, but for additional reading you might want to look up the official tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

And this previous answer that dynamically allocates columns in a tableview. [javafx 2- tableview dynamic column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160715/javafx-2-tableview-dynamic-column)

Best of luck.

Comment: hmm it seams that the effort is not worth, thank you for your effort. Maybe I will try this but your objection is right and maybe I will change that.